# Add active class to section of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm trying to add the class "active" to a section of my menu if one of the links in that section has been clicked. I've recently learnt how to add the active class (using jQuery) to a link in the menu (if it's been clicked) and believe I can tweak this code to get what I want. I've posted it below since it might provide inspiration.

E.g. If lil shorty has been clicked, I want the ul with id="section_3" to get the active class. If Deriving functions is then clicked, I want the ul with id="section_2" to get the active class (and section_3 to lose the active class). Note, on the Deriving functions page, section_2 must also have the "active class".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jack

```js
$(function() {
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
                    .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $(".section li a").each(function() {
    var aurl = $(this).attr("href").substr($(this).attr("href")
                      .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    if (aurl == pgurl || aurl == '')
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul class='section' id='section_2'>
<li><span id='section_title_2' class='section_title'><a href='#' id='section_link_2'>Against the odds.</a></span>
<ul>
<li id='exhibit_1' class='exhibit_title'><a href="../against-the-odds/introduction"> &rarr; Introduction</a></li>
<li id='exhibit_2' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/deriving-functions'> &rarr; Deriving functions</a></li>
<li id='exhibit_3' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/exploiting-odds'> &rarr; Exploiting odds</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
  
<ul class='section' id='section_3'>
<li><span id='section_title_3' class='section_title'><a href='#' id='section_link_3'>Remembering everything.</a></span>
<ul>
<li id='exhibit_104' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>black swans</a></li>
<li id='exhibit_104' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>lil shorty</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for parent() or closest()

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('.section').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.section').addClass('active');
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Thanks for your help (and the links). I've just edited the post. If you clicked "Deriving functions", I would like "active" to still be a class of "section_2" after you arrive onto the deriving functions page. I'm not sure whether your code will do this? Sorry for forgetting to mention this earlier.

Comment: closest will return the first parent matching the selector. So using .section instead of ul should do the trick.